# Segmentation Fault on a recursive FloodFill Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, segmentation-fault

I was assigned to implement a floodfill algorithm by two manners: recursive a
        void RFloodFill(PGM *entrada, int x, int y, unsigned char corAtual,

Comment: Your algorithm is severely broken. In particular, you have infinite descent in the case when `corAtual == novaCor` and (at least) two adjacent pixels are `corAtual`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, the seg fault is occurring when x = -1 and y = 0. This is because you are trying to assign a value to a negative index in the matrix which is not allowed. Since you are trying to modify a place in memory you dont have access to, it seg faults.

`saida->imagem[x][y]=corAtual;` if x is negative here, it will seg fault here, as it is before the check to see if x > 0